# Owl carousel newly added IDs item not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just need to add unique IDs to my owl carousel so I used this code. It's a wordpress website.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
   $.each($('#slider_1180 div.owl-item'), function(ind) {
   $(this).attr('id', 'mainSlide-' + parseInt(ind + 1));
});
});
```

And it's not working. But I copied this code into my **page developer console** and pasted it. Then its working fine. I tried to wrap it on window load function. But it's not working at all.

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $.each($('#slider_1180 div.owl-item'), function(ind) {
   $(this).attr('id', 'mainSlide-' + parseInt(ind + 1));
});
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `div.owl-item`s are created after document.ready/window.load fires.

Comment: Ah I see, So how am I add them?

Comment: We should see how and when those divs are created, otherwise it's impossible to say anything more accurate.